# Question on use of the 'first' conditional in the past (no modal involved)

Tags: conditionals

Which conditional is this?

```
If John did not come to work yesterday, he was probably ill.
```

I would hazard a guess that it is a first conditional as there is a fair probability that John being ill was actually the reason for not coming to work, however all the references I have indicate that the first conditional is for the future only.

Thanks for any comments / explanations!

Edit - a context for clarity: I had imagined a conversation between two work colleagues for example:

> Bob: I couldn’t get the numbers I needed from John yesterday as he was
> out of the office.  Bill: Hmm. If John was out of the office, he was
> probably ill. I’ll check whether he is back today and if he is not,
> I’ll find some numbers for you

Comment: The issue here is **you already know** what happened yesterday, and you are merely speculating about the cause: "**As** John did not come to work yesterday, he was probably ill." You can't really use *if* at all -- or at least, if *if* might be used colloquially, it's colloquial and colloquialisms don't follow a strict grammar like numbered conditionals.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I guess a context might help. I had imagined a conversation between two work colleagues for example:

Bob: I couldn’t get the numbers I needed from John yesterday as he was out of the office. 
Bill: Hmm. If John was out of the office, he was probably ill. I’ll check whether he is back today and if he is not, I’ll find some numbers for you

Comment: I think that comes under the colloquial usage, in that it's a "conditional" that you already know. I suggest adding the context to the question so that people don't have to read all the comments.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: I don't answer questions that mention the "Nth Conditional"; they're already misled and the questions are always a jumble.

Comment: Thanks Andrew...